# Approximating the Logit-Normal by Dirichlet

Tags: distributions, approximation, dirichlet-distribution, logit-normal-distribution

There is a known approximation of the Dirichlet Distribution by a Logit-Normal, as presented in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution).
However, I am interested in the reverse, can I approximate a logit-normal by a Dirichlet?

I.e. Exists an explicit expression for the concentration paramters $\alpha$, given the parameters of the Logit-Normal $\mu, \Sigma$?

Comment: Isn't "approximates" a symmetric relation?  If not, what kind of asymmetry concerns you?

Comment: @whuber KL divergence isn't symmetric

Comment: @Cat That is true.  I had believed it irrelevant to the question, but a close look at the Wikipedia reference shows it was used for the approximation, so you make a very perceptive point.

Comment: Maybe we can ease the problem. Is the KL (forward or reverse does not matter) between Logit-Normals and Dirichlet known? Probably yes, as Aitchinson derived a solution in the wiki link, but his paper is hidden behind a paywall.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches: iterative and closed-form Laplace Bridge.
See below.

## Iterative Newton-Raphson

Given Logistic Normal $p(x \mid \mu,\Sigma)$ and Dirichlet $q(x \mid \alpha)$, the objective is to minimize the KL divergence $\mathbb{KL}(p \parallel q)$ (see [Stanford cs228 note (2023)](https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/inference/variational/) for the specific choice of KL divergence):

$$
L=\mathbb E_p[-\log \tilde q(x \mid \alpha)] + \log\frac{\prod_{d=1}^D \Gamma(\alpha_d)}{\Gamma(\sum_{d=1}^D \alpha_d)}+C\,,\tag{1}
$$

where $C$ is a irrelevant constant and $\tilde q$ is the unnormalized Dirichlet:

$$
\tilde q(x \mid \alpha) = \prod_{d=1}^D x_d^{\alpha_d-1}\,.
$$

Note here, we extract the normalization constant out of the expectation.

Equation (1) yields:

$$
\mathbb E_p[-\log \tilde q(x \mid \alpha)]
= -\mathbb E_p \left[\sum_{d=1}^D (\alpha_d-1)\log x_d\right]
= -\sum_{d=1}^D (\alpha_d-1) \mathbb E_p[\log x_d]\,,\tag{2}
$$

where $\mathbb E_p[\log x_d]$ can be evaluated using reparameterization trick ([Kingma and Welling (2014)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114); [Jankowiak and Obermeyer (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.01851)) followed by Monte Carlo estimate.

Finally, with all the pieces in hand, to optimize Equation (1), while plain old gradient descent may be used, we may adopt instead a linear-time Newton-Raphson method ([Ronning (1989)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949658908811178); [Minka (2000)](https://tminka.github.io/papers/dirichlet/minka-dirichlet.pdf); [Blei et al. (2003)](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf?ref=https://githubhelp.com)), with update rule on $\alpha$:

$$
\alpha := \alpha - H(\alpha)^{-1} g(\alpha)\,.
$$

Here, $g(\alpha)$, the gradient of Equation (1), can be written as:

$$
g_j(\alpha) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \alpha_j}
= -\mathbb E_p[\log x_j] + \psi(\alpha_j) - \psi(\textstyle\sum\nolimits_{d=1}^D \alpha_d)\,,
$$

whereas $H(\alpha)$, the Hessian, can be written as:

$$
H_{ij}(\alpha) = \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial\alpha_i\partial\alpha_j}
= \delta_{ij} \psi'(\alpha_i) - \psi'(\textstyle\sum\nolimits_{d=1}^D \alpha_d)\,.
$$

where $\psi(\cdot)$ is the digamma function, $\psi'(\cdot)$ is the trigamma function, and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta function, which is one iff $i=j$ else zero.

Since the Hessian admits the form $H = \operatorname{diag}(h) + \mathbf 1 z \mathbf 1^\top$, the $H^{-1}g$ can be computed in linear time:

$$
(H^{-1}g)_i = \frac{g_i-c}{h_i}\,,\quad c= \frac{\sum_{d=1}^D g_d/h_d}{z^{-1}+\sum_{d=1}^D h_d^{-1}}\,.
$$

In this spirits, let's attack a 1-D example, where the Dirichlet reduces to Beta distribution.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.distributions import Normal
from torch import nn
from torch import optim


def logsigmoid(z):
    return -torch.logaddexp(torch.zeros_like(z), -z)


def loss_fn(a, b, mu, sigma):
    eps = Normal(0, 1).sample([1000])
    return (torch.mean(
            - (a - 1) * logsigmoid(mu + sigma * eps)
            - (b - 1) * logsigmoid(-mu - sigma * eps))
            + torch.lgamma(a) + torch.lgamma(b)
            - torch.lgamma(a + b))


def train_SGD(mu, sigma):
    a = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(1.))
    b = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(1.))
    optimizer = optim.SGD([a, b], lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
    losses = []
    n_epoch = 100
    for _ in range(n_epoch):
        loss = loss_fn(a, b, mu, sigma)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        losses.append(loss.item())
    return losses, a.item(), b.item()


def train_NewtonRaphson(mu, sigma):
    a = torch.tensor(1.)
    b = torch.tensor(1.)
    for _ in range(50):
        eps = Normal(0, 1).sample([1000])
        x = mu + sigma * eps
        da, db, dab = torch.digamma(a), torch.digamma(b), torch.digamma(a + b)
        ga = -torch.mean(logsigmoid(x)) + da - dab
        gb = -torch.mean(log1msigmoid(x)) + db - dab
        ha, hb = torch.polygamma(1, a), torch.polygamma(1, b)
        z = -torch.polygamma(1, a + b)
        c = (ga / ha + gb / hb) / (1 / z + 1 / ha + 1 / hb)
        a -= (ga - c) / ha
        b -= (gb - c) / hb
    return a.item(), b.item()


def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    

def sample(a, b, mu, sigma):
    Betas = stats.beta(a, b).rvs(size=10000)
    LogitNormals = sigmoid(stats.norm(mu, sigma).rvs(size=10000))
    return Betas, LogitNormals


# experiment 1
mu, sigma = torch.tensor(0.), torch.tensor(1.)
# experiment 2
mu, sigma = torch.tensor(1.), torch.tensor(2.)

# either use SGD
_, a, b = train_SGD(mu, sigma)
# or use Newton-Raphson
a, b = train_NewtonRaphson(mu, sigma)

B, LN = sample(a, b, mu, sigma)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.hist(B, bins=100, density=True)
ax1.set_title('Beta')
ax2.hist(LN, bins=100, density=True)
ax2.set_title('LogitNormal')
```

The SGD typically takes 80 ms, while Newton-Raphson takes 20 ms.
The code produces the following plots, where the left are the solution Beta, and the right are the groundtruth Logit Normal:

[image: fit beta to logit normal]

[image: fit beta to logit normal 2]

## Closed-form Laplace Bridge

[Hobbhahn et al. (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.01227) gave the bidirectional approximation formulae, which is different from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution) formula:

Providing Dirichlet parameter $\alpha$, the approximated Logistic Normal parameters are:

$$
\begin{gather}
\mu_j = \log\alpha_j - \frac{1}{D}\sum_{d=1}^D \log\alpha_d\,;\tag{3.1}\\
\Sigma_{jj} = \frac{1}{\alpha_j} \left(1 - \frac{2}{D}\right) + \frac{1}{D^2}\sum_{d=1}^D \frac{1}{\alpha_d}\,;\tag{3.2}\\
\Sigma_{ij} = 0\,\quad(i \ne j)\,.\tag{3.3}\\
\end{gather}
$$

Providing Logistic Normal parameters $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, the approximated Dirichlet parameters are:

$$
\alpha_j = \frac{1}{\Sigma_{jj}} \left(1 - \frac{2}{D} + \frac{e^{\mu_j}}{D^2} \sum_{d=1}^D e^{-\mu_d}\right)\tag{4}\,.
$$

Note, however, that Equations (3.1-3.3,4) does not hold precisely all the time.
In particular, since the parameter space (basically, $\mathbb R^D \times \mathbb R^{D \times D}$) of Logistic Normal is much larger than that of a Dirichlet (basically, $\mathbb R_+^D$), Equation (4) admits good approximation only for certain choice of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$.
The rule of thumb, which probably sounds uninformative, is that, if the $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ can be yielded by some $\alpha$ under Equations (3.1-3.3), then they can be approximated by that $\alpha$.